# Foreacast Combinations: derivation of minimum MSE / variance approach

Tags: forecasting, mse, forecast-combination, minimum-variance

I am just despairing of the derivation of the minimum variance procedure. The method of the combination of forecasts was first established in 1969 by Bates and Granger. They also invented the minimum variance method.

Here is an excerpt from the paper:
[image]

My problem with this is that I don't understand where the error variance is minimized. To me it looks like the forecast with the highest error variance gets the highest weight, since you would have to take the terms to the power of minus. Maybe I am missing something or have a thinking error.

Comment: $K_T$ is the "weight for the first set." Assuming "set" means "series" and the "first set" corresponds to a subscript $1,$ then as $E_2$ (for the *second* set) increases, the weight on the first set also increases.  That's intuitively the right behavior.  Have I misinterpreted anything?

Comment: Yes Kt is the weight for the first forecast. Thank you for your explanation. My fault was that i thougt Kt is the weight for the second forecast.